# Get "latest comment date" of a Wordpress page in a loop

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

Is there a simple way to get the "latest comment date" of a wordpress page?

For the page itself there is a simple solution like this:

```
get_the_date('Y-m-d', $post->ID)
```

For example this will not work for me (especially since i can't define the last comment either):

```
get_comment_date( 'Ymd', $post->ID);
```

And my array way doesnt work. The "`comment_count`" is fine, but the "`get_comment_date( 'd\/m\/Y' )`" is always the same date, for all pages - why?

```
$args = array(
'post_id' => $post->ID,
'posts_per_page' => 10,
'post_type' => 'page',
'orderby'   => 'date',
'category_name' => 'MyName');

$myposts = get_posts( $args );
foreach ( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); ?>

<?php echo '<div class="comments ' . get_comment_date( 'd\/m\/Y' ) . '"><span>'. $comments_count .'<span></div>'; ?>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Just to clarify, do you need to get the latest comment for all pages? If so, then why are you passing `'post_id' => $post->ID,` argument? Or do you need to get the latest comment for a specific page?

Comment: @Ruvee Yes, I need it for a specific page, but I dont want to write in a fix ID, it should get it dynamically through the "foreach loop" & "$post->ID" ...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Get Latest Comment of a Post in WordPress?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33891551/how-to-get-latest-comment-of-a-post-in-wordpress)

Comment: @MattRaines Thx for the link, but that is something it tried and it doesnt work for me. The problem there was the "two loops" I got with this. Maybe I implemented it wrong in my existing foreach loop from above. Have you an example how it would look like in your way?

Comment: So you're trying to get the latest comment for each page in this `$myposts` loop?

Comment: @Ruvee Yes, absolutely right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you're trying to get the most current comment for a specific page. So, I'd use [`get_comments`<sup>Docs</sup>](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_comments/) function.

```php
$comment_args = array(
  'post_type' => 'page',
  'post_id'   => get_the_id(), // Or if you're in a page loop, you could use $post->ID instead of get_the_id()
  'number'    => 1,
);

$latest_comment = get_comments($comment_args);

// This would give you the latest comment
print_r($latest_comment[0]->comment_content);

// This would give you the comment date
print_r($latest_comment[0]->comment_date);

// This would give you the comment date in gmt
print_r($latest_comment[0]->comment_date_gmt);
```

Note that the `'number' => 1,` would retrieve the latest comment.

---

So your entire code with a loop for pages would be something like this:

```php
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'post_type'      => 'page',
);

$query = new WP_Query($args);

while ($query->have_posts()) {
    $query->the_post();

    the_title();

    $comment_args = array(
        'post_id'   => get_the_ID(),
        'number'    => 1,
    );

    $latest_comment = get_comments($comment_args);

    ?>
    <div class="comments"><?php echo $latest_comment[0]->comment_date; ?></div>
    <hr>
    <?php
};

wp_reset_postdata();
```

Here's the results:

[image]

Let me know if that's what you were looking for!